# When to supply default arguments as template arguments

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U = T>
struct Test{};
template<typename T>
void func(Test<T>){  //#1
}
int main(){
  func(Test<int>{});  //#2
}
```

It seems to no rule in the standard that mentioned what situation the default argument is required for template-parameter.

In [dcl.fct.default#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.default#1)

> If an initializer-clause is specified in a parameter-declaration this initializer-clause is used as a default argument. Default arguments will be used in calls **where trailing arguments are missing**.

In this section, the rule explicitly describe when to supply default arguments for a function call. However I haven't found a quote in the standard similar with the above sentence that describes when to supply default arguments as template arguments.

Such as `Test<T>` at `#1`. Maybe at `#1`, the specialization would be `Test<T,T>`, It's just inference. However, there's no formally terminology explicitly describe this in the standard.

The only quote that implies the default arguments as template arguments  is in the following rule:
[temp#arg-8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#arg-8)

> When a simple-template-id does not name a function, a default template-argument **is implicitly instantiated when the value of that default argument is needed**. [ Example:
> template<typename T, typename U = int> struct S { };
> S<bool>* p;         // the type of p is S<bool, int>*
> The default argument for U is **instantiated to form the type** S<bool, int>*.     — end example ]

Consider the code at `#1`, Does the default argument need at `#1`? If it is(It seems to It need at that point because If I don't specify a default argument for template parameter U, then at the point `#1` will occur an error. see [godbolt outcome](https://godbolt.org/z/4P9q7v)), According to the above quote, the default template-argument need to be **implicitly instantiated**, However at this point, `T` is a template-parameter and the definition of such function template instantiate nothing(It's just a function template definition at this point). So, How does the quote interpret this?

Comment: ["When needed"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#arg-8).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I have read that before write this question. My reading is that the quote is just about  what situation the default argument will be **implicitly instantiated**

Comment: Not just. The example there is not a coincidence.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica However it reback to the question itself again, what situation `the value of that default argument is needed` ? It should have a similar sentence like `Default arguments will be used in template-argument-list where trailing arguments are missing.`, It will describe what situation `the value of that default argument is needed`, Do you agree?

Comment: I do not actually. A reader of the standard is capable of understanding that the cases "when needed" includes the case where an explicit argument is not provided. It also potentially includes more (which I think is by design).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica All right, however for `Test<T>`, how to `implicitly instantiate` a **dependent type**, It just a function template.

Comment: What? `Test` is not a function template

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Typo, I refer to `void func(Test<T>)`. thereof, the parameter is equivalent to `Test<T,T>`, when invoke the function, template argument deduction will perform for each `T`, However, before invocation, How implicitly instantiate the default argument `T`? It just a dependent type.

Comment: The function template definition does not instantiate anything. That happens later during template argument deduction at the call site. Which come to thick of it is probably why the normative text goes with "when needed".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  This determines what `P` is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62876638/11796722)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica In other words, Is the default argument needed at the point of `#1`? if it is, then according to the rule, the  default template-argument  will be implicitly instantiated. However, at that point , there's nothing to be instantiated because it's a function template definition. So, how to interpret this?

Comment: c++20 has more clarity on what makes a valid template id here: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#6 In your case without a default argument, Test<T> is invalid for every T, so it would be impossible to instantiate a valid template so the program is ill formed. With the default argument I think it would be hard to argue that Test<T> is anything other than Test<T, T>, though I can't see anywhere that this is explicitly stated.

Comment: @JosephIreland  Yes, it's the question itself. There's no any quote says that Test<T> is considered as Test<T,T>. The quote in my question just describes the situation when template-parameter has the value of template argument, In that case , the default argument is instantiated, however I think it's not the case of a template definition.

Comment: @jackX I think you would get better responses if you try to create an ambiguous program and ask a question about that - something you believe should have a different compilation result depending on how you interpret the standard. To me it seems all the examples you listed are clearly errors no matter how you read the standard so they don't really show that the standard is inconsistent/incomplete in any way, just that the error message you get is possibly unclear.

Comment: If no such program exists then the standard is perfectly fine, and if you think there is one, then giving an explicit example of the ambiguity makes it much easier to reason about.

Comment: @JosephIreland  Template instantiation is not observable. I only according to these errors to infer how these compiler process. And according to what the standard says to assume how a compiler should process.

Comment: @jackX that's not true, if you make an invalid template instantiation then the program is ill formed. And overload resolution can definitely be observable. For instance, in your example if the deduction "found" Test<int> and a conversion operator existed, then the result could be different, i.e. in [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/3d5K8b) removing the <int> is a compile error. 
If there isn't an observable difference then I guess the only issue is readability of the standard, not it's completeness or consistency.

Comment: @JosephIreland No,  because you explicitly specified the template argument for template parameter `T`, and that will result in default argument instantiation to form `Test<int,int>` , hence the adjusted function type is `void(Test<int,int)`, So there's nothing else that need to deduce, and only conversion happen here. if you call the function like `func(Test<int,char>{})` , the deduction will be failure. see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#5

Comment: @jackX I'm aware it doesn't work (though that quote doesn't explain why, it just says to fill in default args with deduced args, and that's fine here). I somehow (maybe incorrectly) gathered from your other comments that you thought maybe the standard didnt require the defaulted argument to be considered a deduced context, only the first argument. If that were true then it could disregard the second parameter during deduction and instantiate it using the default, i.e. from the first arg which can be deduced as int.

Comment: @JosephIreland  Yes, because dependent type can't cause instantiation. only the first template parameter was deduced and achieved a template argument. The specialization would be as if it likes `Test<int>` at the end of deduction, where the template argument `int` from deduction.  Such specialization will result in instantiation to form `Test<int,int>`.

Answer (score 2):

There is also this paragraph inside [[temp.names]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#6):

> A template-id is valid if

> - there is an argument for each non-deducible non-pack parameter that does not have a default template-argument,

So one could consider that a *default-argument is needed* means a default-argument is needed in order to make the template-id valid and that when there lacks a template argument, the argument is the default argument value. But I have not found anything explicit in the standard for class templates. For function template this is more [explicit](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.fct.spec#temp.deduct-5.sentence-4). Probably nobody pointed out this hole in the standard because this is a common pattern: *default is used in place of what is not user provided*. Maybe it will not be changed because the definition of default in the english dictionary is already given:

> IT. the way that something will happen or appear automatically, especially on a computer, if you do not make any different choices
> -- [cambrige online dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/default)

Comment: I don't think the quote implies so much, I think it only says an argument must be explicitly supplied for these non-deduced template-parameter to make the template-id be vaild. In addition, [dcl.fct.default](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct.default#1) has explicitly specified when to supply default arguments for function call, why not add a similar sentence for template default arguments.

Comment: @JackX What I suppose is that they considered it so obvious that they have probably not even noticed the sentence is lacking.

Comment: I prefer to consider it as a defect , because in the standard, There are corresponding rules for when to supply default arguments for function call and [function template parameter](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#5) respectively, only not for class template.

Comment: @jackX Yes this one is in my answer too...(click on the word explicit) I think there are a lot of holes like this one in the standard. I believe that even the most precisely constructed mathematical theory are also based on some form of hard to recognize "a priori". But for the other related question, the standard even with "a priori" looks unclear to me, maybe I fill the holes with may habits.

Comment: But ,as you said. In order to make the template-id be valid, the default argument is needed. That will make [temp#argu](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#arg-8) contradict itself.  Because at #1, there's no any instantiation that would be occured since at that point, the entity is just template definition.

Comment: @jackX My opinion is the same as yours and you reached such an expertise on the subject that discussing with me will not be productive. I think you should try to reach committe members on std-discussion or on c++ slack.

Comment: I have did that. as far as now, There's no correctly response about it. I hope you can note the discussion on std-discussion, see https://lists.isocpp.org/std-discussion/2020/07/0703.php

Comment: @jackX I saw it. You got a pragmatic answer: the answer argument is based on a usefullness principle. From what I have read, poeple that work on making the standard consistent usually start by saying what is unclear in the standard (not what is wrong, or what is lacking).

Comment: @jackX I've seen many of your questions lately, and I would really like to emphasize Oliv's point from above: _"[...] you reached such an expertise on the subject that discussing with me will not be productive"_ - I don't think SO may prove to be the best forum to get non-ambigious answers to possibly non-discovered defects in the standard. Tbh I think the answer you got on your isocpp was a bit snide, arguably assuming you did you not actually know what you were asking about. I would suggest trying out again, or by other means, ways to discuss deep standard details with isocpp active members.

Comment: @dfri Many questions of mine is about the standard. And I add a tag `language-lawyer` in my question. I believe there're many language lawyer gurus on SO. and many standard committee  members on SO. I hope I can get precisely answers on SO. as the same as I have post some question on std-discussion, however The answer I got is not as good as that on `SO`.

Comment: @jackX Ah my last comment was in no way meant as a criticism to your SO questions (I enjoy language lawyer questions the most myself), but more of an advice to consider reaching our more (perhaps in parallel to your SO questions) to active isocpp members via other forums than SO, as you are seemingly going through the standard with a fine-tooth comb, and you may be likely to find passages that have holes in them (and, possibly, eventually need to file your own defect report, after discussion with active isocpp members).

Comment: @dfri Thanks for your suggestion. However when I try to post these ideas to std-discussion and I got such snide answers as you may saw at that forum. Except for `SO`, which forums do you advised I can discuss these ideas with these members on that?

Comment: @jackX I've never really traversed outside of SO myself for C++ discussions, but I've seen some familiar gurus at reddits c++ page, maybe that could be an alternative. But the isocpp mailing list does sound like the de facto place to find the committe experts, maybe you have just been unlucky so far. Sorry!

Comment: @jackX dfri told you why: the problem is the form, your mail looked naive. I think you should first introduce what you think is unclear, site the right paragraph of the standard, and using a precise wording as u used to do. maybe reads other mails on std-discussion and better, defects reports on open-std.org in order to give to your mail the expected form. Otherwise poeple who read the mail could think you are a newbie that does not understand the standard. This what I think happened to your last mail

Answer (score 0):

> According to the above quote, the default template-argument need to be implicitly instantiated, However at this point, `T` is a template-parameter and the definition of such function template instantiate nothing(It's just a function template definition at this point). So, How does the quote interpret this?

The key is the difference between *need of instantiation* and *when referenced*. In the example from [[temp.arg]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg#8), the default template argument for `U` is instantiated because *it is needed for the instantiation* of `S<bool>`, which unambiguously resolves to `S<bool, int>`. In the OP's own example, instantiation of the instantiation-dependent default template argument for `U` will only follow *after* overload resolution resolves `void func(Test<T>)` as the best viable overload and thus instantiates it. Just inspecting candidate overloads as part of overload resolution, however, will not lead to instantiation of any of the candidates nor any of the function template candidates parameters that are, themselves, templates. It will, however, be *referencing* said template parameters as part of the overload resolution process (discarding non-viable candidates).

---

From [[temp.deduct]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#1) [**emphasis** mine]:

> When a function template specialization **is referenced**, **all of the template arguments shall have values**. The values **can be explicitly specified or**, in some cases, be deduced from the use or **obtained from default** *template-arguments*. [...]

For the OP's particular example, the former (instantiation) only occurs **after overload resolution has finished** and a best viable overload has been instantiated (which in turn instantiates the class template function argument). The latter (a function/class template specialization being referenced to), however, applies also **during overload resolution**, even when discarding candidates that are either not viable or not the best viable match, candidates that will never lead to instantiations.

From [[temp.deduct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#2) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **When an explicit template argument list is specified, the template arguments must be compatible with the template parameter list** and must result in a valid function type as described below; otherwise type deduction fails. Specifically, the following steps are performed when evaluating an explicitly specified template argument list with respect to a given function template:
>
> - (2.1) **The specified template arguments** must match the template parameters in kind (i.e., type, non-type, template). There must **not be more arguments** than there are parameters unless [...]

and from [[temp.deduct]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#6) [**emphasis** mine]:

> At certain points in the template argument deduction process it is necessary to take a function type that makes use of template parameters and replace those template parameters with the corresponding template arguments. This is done **at the beginning of template argument deduction** when any explicitly specified template arguments are substituted into the function type, and again **at the end of template argument deduction** when any template arguments that were deduced or obtained from default arguments are substituted.

it is clear that as part of the *"end of template argument deduction"*, any template arguments that have not been explicitly specified will be either deduced or obtained from default arguments and substituted into the candidate function before discarding or ranking it as a viable overload. This applies without any relation to *instantiation*, and only in the context of a given specialization (that may not yet or ever be instantiated) being *referenced*, as part of overload resolution.

Finally, from [[temp.deduct.type]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#3) [**emphasis** mine]:

> A given type `P` can be composed from a number of other types, **templates**, and non-type values:
>
> - [...]
> - (3.3) A type **that is a specialization of a class template** (e.g., `A<int>`) **includes the types**, templates, and non-type values **referenced by the template argument list of the specialization**.

we note that as part of function template argument deduction for a function template parameter that is a specialization of a class template, the function template parameter type (used for deduction against an argument) includes the types *referenced by the template argument list* of the template parameter, meaning the particular class template specialization (function template argument) is *referenced*, so that, as per [temp.deduct]/1, it will go through template argument deduction and default-argument inspection for any of its template arguments that are not explicitly specified.

Comment: Do you mean, the template argument deduction firstly deduced template argument for `T` which is the template-parameter of the function template, then The deduction process step into the `the end of template argument deduction`, that is, These deduced arguments,  or obtained from default arguments(if any) from function template declaration is substituted into the function type, the parameter of the substitution as if it like `Test<int>`, then [temp#arg-8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#arg-8) rule performes for such `template-id` and the final resulting is `Test<int,int>`,Right?

Comment: @jackX I would agree to everything but the final part: [temp.arg]/8 is not relevant for _"When to supply default arguments as template arguments"_, it only apples *after* overload resolution *has finished* if a viable candidate has actually been found. Note that everything in my answer  above covers only overload resolution, and how function template argument deduction applies when attempting to find whether a _candidate function_ is actually a _viable candidate function_. The latter, if the viable candidate is ranked as best, will lead to instantiation of the function and thus also ...

Comment: ... the default template arg., but this is not relevant here, as we are only studying the template argument deduction part of overload resolution, which does not, by itself, instantiate anything, it just inspects candidates ("references" them, if you will). Thus, you question regarding the instantiation of the default template arg. and the fact that we are considering a primary template definition are orthogonal - the default template arg. of the class template spec. will only ever need to be instantiated if the function template is actually picked by overload resolution and instantiated.

Comment: Afacs [temp.deduct.type]/3 (see final part in my answer above) is key here, not [temp.arg]/8. Again, we are not considering any need of instantiation until overload resolution **is finished**, and the relevant passages quoted above all apply to argument deduction as part of overload resolution **before it has finished**. We want to analyze how a candidate function is deemed _viable or not_. If it is eventually chosen and instantiated, then `Test<int, int>` will be instantiated along with ("as needed" by [temp.arg]/8).

Comment: Yes, I agree what you are saying, `the final resulting is Test<int,int>` in my above comment means after the overload resolution has selected that function specialization as called function, then that parameter is instantiated to form `Test<int, int>`. Do you agree?

Comment: In addition, I have to say the compiler resulting of clang or gcc both says that `T` is conflicting as  int vs. char, if you pass the argument of type `Test<int, char>`to the function template. That sounds like the parameter of function template is `Test<T, T>`, each template parameter  is use to participate the template argument deduction, and get difference value of template argument. I think if the compiler process it according to our analysis step, It would report the type of parameter is not matched with that of actually argument, Right?

Comment: @jackX I agree with both your statements!

Comment: It is not explicitly specified in the standard, the behavior of both compiler seems to the default argument is supplied at the point of definition, that is `Test<T,T>`. However our analysis is that the default argument is instantiated to form `Test<int, int>` at the point of instantiation if the argument type is `Test<int,int>`. I think it's  unclear in the standard.

Comment: Wait. I think instantiate default argument to form `Test<int, int>` should occur within  overload resolution, due to [temp.deduct#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#5), If the parameter is not a clear type, how to determine which is the best viable candidate?

Comment: according to [over.match#2.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match#2.9), In order to find the best viable candidate, the type of the corresponding parameter shall be determined.

Comment: [over.match#footnote-124](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match#footnote-124) evidence what I say.