# How does the template argument deduction perform for function template parameter when it is a class template with default argument

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U = T>
struct Test{};

template<typename T>
void func(Test<T>){  //#1
}

int main(){
  func(Test<int>{});  //#2
}
```

Consider the above code, At the point of invocation of function template `func`, the type of argument is `Test<int,int>`, When call the function template, template argument deduction will perform.

The rule  of template argument deduction for function call is :
[temp.deduct#call-1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#call-1)

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it P) that contains template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it A) as described below.

I'm pretty sure the type of `A` is `Test<int,int>`, however I'm not sure what the type of `P` here is.  Is it `Test<T>` or `Test<T,T>`, According to the rule, It seems to the type of `P` here is `Test<T>`, then deduction process is performed to determine the value of `T` that participate in template argument deduction.  Then according to  these rules described as the following:

[temp.deduct#call-4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#call-4)

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A identical to A (after the type A is transformed as described above).

[temp.deduct#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#5)

> When all template arguments have been deduced or obtained from default template arguments, all uses of template parameters in the template parameter list of the template and the function type are replaced with the corresponding deduced or default argument values.

Because the class template `Test` has a default argument, hence the deduced `T` is substituted into default argument. That means the deduced `A` is `Test<int,int>` and it is identical to Argument type `Test<int,int>`.

However, It's just my understanding. I'm not sure what type the `P` here is.  If change the type of function argument to `Test<int,double>`, the [outcome](https://godbolt.org/z/hronoz) will report:

```
candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('int' vs. 'double')
```

The outcome looks like as if the `P` is `Test<T,T>` and the fist value of `T` is conflicting with the second value of `T`.

So, My question is:

Whether the `P` here is `Test<T>` or `Test<T,T>`? and why?

Comment: Did you try to compile it? boost has a type_index library where you can pretty print types with CVR. This question would benefit from results and a 'why' instead of pure 'theorycrafting' where you leave the work to others.

Comment: @sweenish I have compiled the code, the outcome is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zcfTK5), it's a valid code.

Comment: It should go into the question. Wandbox allows you to use boost.

Comment: @sweenish That doesn't matter. The question is discussing the type of `P` here when perform a template argument deduction for a function call.

Comment: And I'm saying that there's literally no "language-lawyering" needed unless you need a 'why'. You're asking for 'what', and that's self-discoverable.

Comment: @sweenish I need a 'why'

Comment: Test<T> and Test<T,T> are the same type. Why would they be different? Test takes two type parameters. Test<T> just deduces to Test<T,T>.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Test<T> is a valid `template-id`(since there's a default argument for the second template parameter), However at the point of function template definition, there's no any instantiation to instantiate default arguments to form `Test<T, T>`. see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg#8. That means the second template parameter does not participate the template argument deduction. only when first template parameter was deduced and then instantiate default argument to form `Test<int, int>`(if actual type is `Test<int,int>`).

Comment: @jack X  My point is that the compiler most likely expands Test<T> to Test<T,T> at some point. Test is a template with two template arguments at the end of the day, always. Test<T> is just a shorthand for Test<T,T> by using the default template argument. The compiler is therefore matching Test<T,T> against Test<int,int>.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 However there's no any special rules describes that `Test<T>` will be expanded to `Test<T,T>` in the standard.

Comment: @jack X What else could it be? The compiler interprets Test<T> as Test with the template arguments T T by the default argument. The difference is simply surface-level.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 That's not what the standard says. The standard only says `When a simple-template-id does not name a function, **a default template-argument is implicitly instantiated** when the value of that default argument is needed. ` At that point, there's no any instantiation will occur.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 And in the latest standard draft, it says `A template-id is valid if there is an argument for each non-deducible non-pack parameter that does not have a default template-argument`, due to class template `Test` has a default argument for the second template parameter, So within the function template definition of `func`, `Test<T>` is considered as a valid template-id .

Comment: @jack X I see. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

*not a language lawyer answer*

There is no type `Test<T>` is actually a "shorthand" for `Test<T, T>`.

Just like with default function arguments if you have `int foo(int a, int b = 24)` the type of the function is `int (int, int)` and any call like `foo(11)` is actually `foo(11, 24)`.

Comment: The question is that there's no quote that discribes this in the standard  . At least , I couldn't find that.

Answer (score 0):

`P` must be a type not a template. `test <T>` is a template-id, but it is not explicitly said in the standard that the template-id `test <T>` is equivalent to `test<T,T>`. The only thing that is said is:

> A template-id is valid if

> - [...]

> - there is an argument for each non-deducible non-pack parameter that does not have a default template-argument, [...]

After that, holes in the standard are filled by our intuition oriented by the use of the term *default*.

I think the key point here is that a template designate a family, and a template-id cannot designate a family.

Comment: Yes, there's no any quote says that `Test<T>` is equivalent to `Test<T,T>`. However I think even though `Test<T>` is taken as `P`, The deduction process still can be success. Because [temp.deduct.type#9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#9), that is `If P has a form that contains <T> or <i>, then each argument Pi of the respective template argument list of P is compared with the corresponding argument Ai of the corresponding template argument list of A.`. That means P0 is `T` and it is deduced from A0 `int`. That is over, the remain process are substitution.

Comment: Because class template `Test` has a default arguments and the first template parameter has been deduced as `int`, Hence [temp.arg#8](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg#8) rule apply to it , It will be instantiated to form the template-id `Test<int,int>`. However in this situation, the compiler should report the type of parameter and type of arguments are not matched rather than the value of `T` is conflicting, the later sounds like as if the template-id is `Test<T,T>`.

Answer (score 0):

> Whether the `P` here is `Test<T>` or `Test<T,T>`? and why?

`P` is `Test<T,T>`.

---

I think we can agree that the rules of [[temp.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct) applies also for class templates; e.g. [[temp.class.order]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.order), covering partial ordering of class template specializations, is entirely based on the concept of re-writing the class templates to (invented) function templates and applying the rules of function templates to that of the invented function templates corresponding to the original class templates under partial ordering analysis. Combined with the fact that the standard passage for class templates is quite brief in comparison to function templates, I interpret the references below as applying also for class templates.

Now, from [[temp.deduct]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#1) [**emphasis** mine]:

> When a function template specialization **is referenced**, **all of the template arguments shall have values**. The values **can be explicitly specified or**, in some cases, be deduced from the use or **obtained from default** *template-arguments*. [...]

and, from [[temp.deduct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#2) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **When an explicit template argument list is specified, the template arguments must be compatible with the template parameter list** and must result in a valid function type as described below; otherwise type deduction fails. Specifically, the following steps are performed when evaluating an explicitly specified template argument list with respect to a given function template:
>
> - (2.1) **The specified template arguments** must match the template parameters in kind (i.e., type, non-type, template). There must **not be more arguments** than there are parameters unless [...]

With extra emphasis on "***is referenced***" and *"**the specified template arguments**"*; there is no requirement that we specify **all** arguments for a given matching function(/class) template, only that **those that do specify** follow the requirements of [temp.deduct]/2 for explicitly specified template arguments.

This leads us to back to [temp.deduct]/1 for **the remaining template arguments** of a given candidate function/class template: these can be either deduced (function templates) or **obtained from the default template arguments**. Thus, the call:

> ```
> func(Test<int>{});
> ```

is, as per the argument above, semantically equivalent to

```
func(Test<int, int>{});
```

with the main difference that the template arguments for the former is decided by both an explicitly specified template arguments and a default template argument, whereas for the latter both are decided by explicitly specified template arguments. From this, it is clear that `A` is `Test<int, int>`, but we will use a similar argument for `P`.

---

From [[temp.deduct.type]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#3) [**emphasis** mine]:

> A given type `P` can be composed from a number of other types, **templates**, and non-type values:
>
> - [...]
> - (3.3) A type **that is a specialization of a class template** (e.g., `A<int>`) **includes the types**, templates, and non-type values **referenced by the template argument list of the specialization**.

Notice that the description in [temp.deduct.type]/3.3 now returns to the template **argument list** of the **template type** `P`. It doesn't matter that `P`, for when inspecting this particular candidate function in overload resolution, refers to a class template by partly explicitly specifying the template argument list and partly relying on a default template parameter, where the latter is instantiation-dependent. This step of overload resolution does not imply any kind of instantiation, only inspection of candidates. Thus, the same rules as we just applied to the template argument `A` above applies to `P`, in this case, and as `Test<int, int>` is referenced (via `Test<int>`), `P` is `Test<int, int>`, and we have a perfect match for `P` and `A` (for the single parameter-argument pair `P` and `A` of this example)

---

#### Compiler error messages?

Based in the argument above, one could arguably expect a similar error message for the OP's failing example:

> ```
> // (Ex1)
> template<typename T, typename U = T>
> struct Test{};
>
> template<typename T>
> void func(Test<T>) {}
>
> int main() {
>     func(Test<int, double>{});
> }
> ```

as for the following simple one:

```
// (Ex2)
struct Foo {};
template<typename T> struct Test {};
template<typename T> void f(T) {}

int main() {
    f<Test<int>>(Test<Foo>{});
}
```

This is not the case, however, as the former yields the following error messages for GCC and Clang, respectively:

> ```
> // (Ex1)
>
> // GCC
> error: no matching function for call to 'func(Test<int, double>)'
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>         deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('int' and 'double')
>
> // Clang
> error: no matching function for call to 'func'
> note: candidate template ignored: deduced 
>       conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('int' vs. 'double')
> ```

whereas the latter yields the following error messages for GCC and Clang, respectively:

> ```
> // (Ex2)
>
> // GCC
> error: could not convert 'Test<Foo>{}' from 'Test<Foo>' to 'Test<int>'
>
> // Clang
> error: no matching function for call to 'f'
> note: candidate function template not viable: 
>       no known conversion from 'Test<Foo>' to 'Test<int>' for 1st argument
> ```

We can finally note that if we tweak `(Ex1)` into explicitly specifying the **single** template argument of `f`, both GCC and Clang yields similar error messages as for `(Ex2)`, hinting that argument deduction has been entirely removed from the equation.

```
template<typename T, typename U = T>
struct Test{};

template<typename T>
void func(Test<T>) {}

int main() {
    func<int>(Test<int, double>{});
}
```

The key for this difference may be as specified in [[temp.deduct]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#6) [**emphasis** mine]:

> At certain points in the template argument deduction process it is necessary to take a function type that makes use of template parameters and replace those template parameters with the corresponding template arguments. This is done **at the beginning of template argument deduction** when any explicitly specified template arguments are substituted into the function type, and again **at the end of template argument deduction** when any template arguments that were deduced or obtained from default arguments are substituted.

namely that the template argument deduction process is separated into a clear *beginning* and *end*, categorizing:

- explicitly specified template arguments as the beginning of the process, and,
- deduced or default argument-obtained template arguments as the end of the process,

which would explain the differences in the error messages of the examples above; if all template arguments have been explicitly specified in the beginning of the deduction process, the remainder of the process will not have any remaining template argument to work with w.r.t. deduction or default template arguments.

Comment: I think `P` at the point of function template definition shall be still `Test<T>` rather than`Test<T,T>`, as you  answered in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62875215/when-to-supply-default-arguments-as-template-arguments).

Comment: @jackX That was not the argument I was trying to make in my other answer. Note that `P` ever only exists as part of template argument deduction for a given function template argument. As per [temp.deduct.type]/3 above, _”`P` is ... A type that is a **specialization** of a class template (e.g., `A<int>`)”_. Now, `Test<int>` **is not the specialization of** `Test`; the specialization is `Test<int, int>` and the former is just _referencing the latter specialization_. Any full template specialization includes the full specification of all template parameters of said specialization, do you agree?

Comment: So even if we use the syntactic form `Test<int>` we are actually _referencing_ the `Test<int, int>` specialization, and as per [temp.deduct]/6 above the only difference is that the final phase of template argument deduction _for the class template_ `Test` will substitute in the default template argument for the second template parameter. If we _referenced the same specialization_ using the syntactic form `Test<int, int>`, template argument deduction would be complete w.r.t. template argument substitutions after the _beginning_ phase of template argument deduction.

Comment: ... but both forms refer to the same specialization, and as we are entirely in the context of deduction for _candidates_, there is no instantiation happening yet (not of the class template specialization, nor for its default argument, nor for the function template candidate specialization which triggered the chain of template argument deduction).

Comment: In this question, I ask whether the parameter of function  template is `Test<T>` or `Test<T,T>` at template definition , The latter implies that at the function template definition, the default argument of the class template is taken as the second template argument, which seems to the standard does not specify. So, within the function template definition, The parameter is just `Test<T>`, there's no requirement to supply the default argument for such specialization at this point.

Comment: In addition,  I think the instantiation of class template `Test` should occur at the end of template deduction for function template `func` in order to form a specialization that is added to the set of candidate to participate overload resolution. see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match#footnote-124. Otherwise if the type of the parameter is not determined, how overload resolution form a implicit conversion sequence to determine the rank.

Answer (score -1):

I tryed to come up with a code that forces only class deduction without function deduction.
Here, there are no function instantiations, but the compiler emits an error anyway:

```
template<typename T, typename U = T>
struct Test{};

template<typename T> 
void func(Test<T, T>){
}

template<typename T>
void func(Test<T>){  
}
```

`redefinition of 'template<class T> void func(Test<T, T>)'`

GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/7c981E
Clang:
https://godbolt.org/z/G1eKTx

Previous wrong answer:

> P refers to template parameter, not to template itself. In declaration `Test<typename T, typename  U = T>` P refers to T, not to Test. So in the instantiation `Test<int>` T is int, just like A in the call is also int.

Comment: why do you think that P refers to template-parameter? see `function template parameter type (call it P)`.

Comment: because it says that in the first quote you gave  temp.deduct#call-1

Comment: you misunderstand the quote, please read it carefully.

Comment: In the standard, the next line just after the end of the quote is : `If removing references and cv-qualifiers from P gives std​::​initializer_­list<P'> ` ... And little below there is a first example `template<class T> void f(std::initializer_list<T>);` `f({1,2,3});// T deduced to int` in my view, it means using P' = T  ( P' is P removed cv-qualifiers )

Comment: I can't convince you, you should open a question to get the basic knowledge about what actually this P refer to.

Comment: In addition,  P is equiavenlent to std​::​initializer_­list<P'> rather than P'.  P' is a hypothetical function template parameter type that corresponding to argument that from element of initializer list.

Comment: Sorry I think you are right, I looked more to the quote than the sample. The mechanism that instantiates `Test<int>` is not function deduction, is class template explicit instantiation, since you are passing <int> as parameter of Test in #2, it will be explicitly instantiated before function deduction kics in. Standard quote : https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg#8. When function deduction starts, the type of P is Temp<int, int> that is already instantiated with all parameters

Comment: So, you think that  at `#2`  the parameter is `Test<T`> rather than `Test<T,T>`?

Comment: The parameter that enter in Class Deduction yes, the parameter that enters in function deduction no. `Test<int>` became `Test<int, int>`  by class deduction mechanism alone, all before function deduction starts. When function deduction starts, only `Test<int, int>` exists as said in standard temp.arg#8

Comment: "Test<int> became Test<int, int> by class deduction mechanism alone,  all before function deduction starts. "?  I don't think so. That should occur after function template arguments have been deduced.